# Android app (in production) on play store not showing when searched

Tags: android, google-play

I released android app "E numbers detector". App passed google review and I got mail that it is on play store. Weird thing is that I can acces my app only through google play developers console. F.e. If I want to tell my friend to install the app, I can not tell him name of app so he can find it on google store. I must enter my GP console and share url to my app with him via WhatsApp. That is so bad and I don't understand why this happens? I even tried searching my app with app name and developer name combined, or with the package name, but nothing helps.

Here is my app link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=myAndroid.app.hhodzic.foodinspector

I thought also that it has something to do with a number of downloads. But than I found out that the first app that is recommended when you write "E numbers detector" is app with ONLY 10+ downloads.

Please can anyone explain to me how does this works and how can I make my app visible on the google play store. Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the app link here. We can check if it is searchable or not.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Sure no problem. I just added it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just wait for 24-48 hours, Google takes time to index your app in the Google Play search.

I just searched for you app and it did appear in the search results. as I said it just need time.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes it is available now. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Check your app status at [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/console/about/).

App status: Helps you understand your app’s availability on Google Play and who it’s available to (such as testers, all Google Play users, etc.).

[image]

[More info here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751?hl=en#zippy=%2Capp-status)

Comment: Yes I did. And it says that my app status is in PRODUCTION. So regarding that, everything should be fine

Comment: It seems to be local problem, because I can clearly see your app while searching in Google play. Double-check available countries for your app in Google Play Console.

Comment: I ckecked regions and countries and my country (Croatia) has chechmark and is available. Are you sure you found app by just writing its name in search? I tried this on multiple devices and I did not suceed

Comment: Hey I just tried and now it works for me now also! And I did absolutely nothing :D